# Modification of non-creatable array value attempted, subscript -2147483648

Tags: perl, integer-overflow

I am fairly new to Perl, so bear with me..

I am getting this error:

> Modification of non-creatable array value attempted, subscript
>   -2147483648 at...

from this code:

```
while (@data) {
    my $datum = shift @data;
    #print "adding $datum at $an\n";
    $mem[$an] = $datum;
    $an++;
    }
```

mem is declared here:

```
@mem = ();
```

now, the problem popped up when the addresses started exceeding the 2G limit(0x80000000). So this looks to be related to an integer overflow causing the number to be interpereted as negative. How can I tell Perl I am using an unsigned 32 bit integer?

Thanks

Comment: how is $an originally set?

Comment: Do you actually have 2G elements, or is your array sparse? If it's the former, you'll need a 64-bit build of Perl. If it's the latter, consider using something more appropriate data structure (a hash at a minimum).

Answer (score 2):

Try using `push` function.

```
    while (@data) {
        my $datum = shift @data;
        #print "adding $datum at $an\n";
        push (@mem, $datum); ## this adds the new element at the end of the @mem array.
   }
```

To know more about `push`, study [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html).

If you wish to use `hash`, use following code:

```
my %mem = ();
while (@data) {
            my $datum = shift @data;
            #print "adding $datum at $an\n";
            $mem{$an} = $datum;
            $an++; ## Increment the key so as to avoid overwriting of the value.
}
```

Comment: well, I want an associative hash, not an array... I want to do `$mem[$an]`

Answer (score 2):

Use a hash (associative array), not an array.  Perl arrays are not designed to be used that sparsely.

```
my %mem;
...
   $mem{$an} = $datum;
```